# importing database in dockerized postgresql

Tags: postgresql, shell

I'm trying to import my database schema and data into my docker container with `postgresql:9.6`.

I successfully created my database:

```
docker exec <container> psql -U <user> postgres -l

       Name        |       Owner        | Encoding |  Collate   |   Ctype    |   Access privileges
-------------------+--------------------+----------+------------+------------+-----------------------
 <database>        | <user>             | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 |
 postgres          | postgres           | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 |
 template0         | postgres           | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =c/postgres          +
                   |                    |          |            |            | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1         | postgres           | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =c/postgres          +
                   |                    |          |            |            | postgres=CTc/postgres
(4 rows)
```

I'm importing with the following command (I've tried several alternatives as well):

```
docker exec <container> psql -U <user> -d <database> << '<sql dump file>'
heredoc>
```

instead of importing my database it's showing me the `heredoc>` prompt

any clues?

I'm running with osx `iterm 2` and `zsh`

Answer (score 0):

Found my problem,

I was using `<<` rather than `<` to pick the file.. a typo :(